# how do I write my output to a file using file sink to analyze the output data?

Tags: gnuradio

I'm reading binary data from a(two) file(s)(.txt), after performing a logical operation(XOR),writing output to another file(.txt)(using file sink). After I execute the flow graph, and open the file, it shows something like corrupted word document.please help me deal with it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you think would happen? And: Can you describe what you think the XOR function does?

Answer (score 0):

`XOR`ing two printable character bytes may lead to unprintable characters. So your text editor may not be able to open it properly. Try to open the file with a hex editor like `hexdump` or `okteta`.